# How do I change enviroment variables for CI in Cypress?

Tags: continuous-integration, cypress

I need to use different port for my local and CI testing, but I have trouble with Cypress.env

I tried reading global .env settings, but Cypress.env() returns undefined (I am guessing it's because it reads only cypress.env.json file). How can I read them? Or access global variables like dotenv? Or, other option, how can I use different cypress.env.json files for CI? (e.g. use cypress.env.json locally and cypress.env.CI.json on CI)

Comment: Have you tried using [Cypress.config](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/config.html#Syntax)?